# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library ... Cannot allocate memory

Tags: php, imagick, php-5.4, apache2.2, libtiff

I get this error after using simple commands like php -i or php -v.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '`/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/imagick.so`'
>   - `libtiff.so.3`: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory in Unknown on line 0

Shell returns: Out of memory, and then writes error to the `error_log`.

> PHP version: 5.4.36
>
> Apache version: 2.2.29

I've seen questions about similar problem, but most of them have a problem with reading a file from the right path, but I think this is not the case...

Why it cannot alocate memory? How do I fix this? Preferably without server restart :). I have access to `php.ini`.

**UPDATE:**

I have both imagick.so and libtiff.so.3 in the right path. 
After running `ldd imagick.so` I get this warning:

> ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `./imagick.so'
>
> ...
>
> libtiff.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libtiff.so.3 (0x00007f0b0a0af000)
>
> ...

So files are on the right place, but I guess there is a permission problem...
How do I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Is imagick installed?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yes, I believe it is. I have uncommented this line: extension="imagick.so" in php.ini

Comment: @hjpotter92 Do you have anything in mind about how to fix this? Shell returns Out of memory for many commands that im trying to run... Please help :(

Comment: Don't think it's a permissions problem, the warning is okay with ldd. Have you tried this: [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '…' failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory in Unknown on line 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981347/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-failed-to-map-seg)